# Managing multiple concurrent release with git

Tags: git

We are managing the workflow for a product which has multiple releases in production at any given time. This is a relatively new situation for the team and we are not sure of the best to handle this.  We are using git with a private bitbucket repo.

Previously, we were using a develop/master git flow type workflow and it worked great.  More recently, our client has put multiple versions into production and we have to support each of them as if it was it's own product.

E.g. we have 1.1, 1.2 and 1.5 and we must be able to work on and deploy each one without affecting the others. Ideally though, they are in the same project as some changes will be shared between branches, while others will not.

Two possibilities we're investigating:

- Sticking with the develop/master idea but extending it to the different versions e.g v1.1-develop, v1.1-master, v1.2-develop, v1.2-master, etc... This works exactly like our previous flow but with 3 versions of master/develop.
- Using a single branch for each version v1.1, v1.2, v1.5 and tagging when releases occur.  If we need to work on the we pull it by tag, work on it, checkout it out into a new branch and re-tag it.  This version seems very clunky.
- I've also been looking at the git worktrees, but that seems more like #2 because it provides multiple concurrent branches but not multiples of those branches like #1.

Does anyone have an experience with this kind of set up? Is #1 the correct way to do it? Am I missing something with #2 or #3 that would make it more manageable?

Comment: This sounds like more of a philosophical question than one that has a specific answer.

Comment: I can see that but I am actually looking for a process to implement not just for what is the "best" way to do it.

Comment: I know what you're getting at, and it's not a bad question, but it's a bit too open-ended for the format here. Those options you present could work, so there's nothing technically wrong with them. This is the kind of thing that's better presented in a forum where things can be debated, where people can share their stories, something that's a poor fit for this question/answer format.

Answer (score 1):

My company maintains a separate branch for each version, so `1.1`, `1.2`, `2.1`, etc. We then use tags within each branch to mark point releases, so `1.1.7`, `1.2.4`, `2.1.2`.

Branches are used for major/minor versions because that is the deciding point for support/maintenance. We support only a certain number of past "releases" based on this separation.

Each point release is forward progress. We would never have a release `1.1.7` and actually make a change to a `1.1.6`. Issues found would be resolved in `1.1.8`, and would be tagged appropriately.

This seems similar to your #2, but we never actually "pull by tag". We still work based on the branch, which points at the newest commit for each release. The tags are more historical.

That said, this very much depends on how your organization defines its releases and support for those releases. This works very well for our organization, and over time has made it easy for us to ensure that changes make it into the appropriate channels and minimal fighting with git is necessary.